# Basis representation of hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, hamiltonian

I do not understand this representation of a Hamiltonian
involving the basis projection operator and Identity matrix.
$$\begin{align}
\hat{H}_0&=
  \sum_{n_1,l_1,j_1,m_{j1}
  }E_{n_1 l_1 j_1}\left|n_1 l_1 j_1 m_{j1}\right>
  \left<n_1 l_1 j_1 m_{j1}\right|
  \otimes\mathbb{I} \\
&+ \mathbb{I}\otimes
  \sum_{n_2,l_2,j_2,m_{j2}}E_{n_2 l_2 j_2}
  \left|n_2 l_2 j_2 m_{j2}\right>
  \left<n_2 l_2 j_2 m_{j2}\right|
\end{align}$$
Can someone please explain what is going on? I have quoted the Hamiltonian of two non-interacting atoms.

Comment: This has been downvoted (but not by me) because of the screenshotting. That's not well liked here because it's not SE-friendly.

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to display math on the site.  It is the site standard and using images or text or math is very strongly discouraged.

Comment: Sorry, i am new here, the screenshots will not happen again

Answer (score 3):

Each atom is described by an Hamiltonian, which has its own eigenvalues and eigenstates.

In this way, the atom is described by a state space $\mathcal{E_{1,2}}$ where the indeces refer to atom 1 and 2. Now, the full system, comprising of the two atoms, is obtained by performing the tensor product of the two states
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}_1 \otimes \mathcal{E}_2,
\end{equation}
since the atoms are non-interacting. Let $H_1$ be the Hamiltonian of atom 1 and $H_2$ of atom 2. $H_1$ acts on $\mathcal{E}_1$ but not on $\mathcal{E}_2$, and $H_2$ acts on $\mathcal{E}_2$ but not on $\mathcal{E}_1$. Now we extend the action of $H_1$ to all $\mathcal{E}$ in such a way that nothing happens on $\mathcal{E}_2$, which can be done as taking $H_1$ to be $\mathbb{1}$ in $\mathcal{E}_2$. The same goes for $H_2$. As so the Hamiltonian in the full state space $\mathcal{E}$ is
\begin{equation}
H=H_1 \otimes \mathbb{1}+ \mathbb{1}\otimes H_2.
\end{equation}

Each Hamiltonian can be expanded in a basis of its eigenvectors, just as you can always do for any operator given a basis of its eigenvectors that **span all space.** In the case above we have considered that the system is fully described by the complete set $\{H, L, J, J_z\}$ for each atom. Thus
\begin{equation}
H_i=\sum_{n_i, l_i, j_i, m_{ji}} E_{n_i l_i j_i m_{ji}}|n_i l_i j_i m_{ji}\rangle \langle n_i l_i j_i m_{ji}|.
\end{equation}
In the equations you submitted we have further assumed that the energy is degenerate in $m_j$, which is usual in many systems. Now, recalling how we wrote the full Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{n_1, l_1, j_1, m_{j1}} E_{n_1 l_1 j_1 m_{j1}}|n_1 l_1 j_1 m_{j1}\rangle \langle n_1 l_1 j_1 m_{j1}| \otimes \mathbb{1}+ \mathbb{1}\otimes \sum_{n_2, l_2, j_2, m_{j2}} E_{n_2 l_2 j_2 m_{j2}}|n_2 l_2 j_2 m_{j2}\rangle \langle n_2 l_2 j_2 m_{j2}|.
\end{equation}

Comment: Okay! That clears up my doubt, Thank you so much! And also sorry about the screen shot, it won't happen again!